# how to store 13 digit timestamp in cassandra

Tags: cql3

I want to create this table but I want to save datetime in 13 digit timestamp format e.g 1424109603234

```
create table data (
  datetime timestamp,
  id text,
  type text,
  body text  
  primary key (id, type, datetime)
)
```

is the datatype of datetime correct? how should I insert data, in any specific function like toTimestamp(now())??

Answer (score 1):

datatype for datetime is correct.

Values for the timestamp type are encoded as 64-bit signed integers representing a number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as the epoch: January 1 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT. (For more detail refer to https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html
)

Now from your function you need to get the epoch timestamp and then convert it to milliseconds( There are lot of different codes to do that) and then push the converted time stamp (signed long long) to cassandra.